# Kill service by package name

Tags: android, service

I would like to know if can I kill service by package name. I have run service from one app and I want to kill that service from another app. How I can do that?

Comment: I want kill or stop service not all application

Comment: You'll need to put a mechanism in the service so that you can politely ask it to stop.